Is there a cleaner way to implement preprocessor-like conditional XAML variants in WPF?
The Problem
I extensively use C# preprocessor directives to maintain different code variants during development. For example:
#if fix_issue_001
    // new implementation
#else
    // original implementation
#endif

I control these via MSBuild:
msbuild.exe MyProject.csproj /p:DefineConstants="fix_issue_001"

Now I want to extend this pattern to WPF XAML files, but preprocessor directives aren't available there. I've created a working solution (full example here on GitHub), but I'm not satisfied with it as it requires modifying the original code.
Current Solution
In XAML:
<!-- Original version -->
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsOriginalVersion, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <Button Content="Original Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>

<!-- New version -->
<StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsNewVersion, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <Button Content="New Button" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>

Code-behind:
public bool IsOriginalVersion
{
    get
    {
#if fix_issue_001
            return false;
#else
        return true;
#endif
    }
}

public bool IsNewVersion
{
    get
    {
#if fix_issue_001
    return true;
#else
        return false;
#endif

What I'm Looking For

A way to wrap the original XAML in some sort of conditional statement rather than altering it with visibility bindings
A more concise way in the code-behind - ideally just one property/field instead of two methods
Minimal changes to the original code (preferably none)

Is there a better approach to achieve this? Maybe using custom markup extensions, attached properties, or some other WPF feature I'm not aware of?
P.S. I believe I have managed to solve this problem. You may find the source code here and the NuGet package here.
